# PHP loop in an email function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

I have an email function that looks like:

```
function send_email_with_attachment($to, $from, $email_att, $subject, $body)
```

I have 2 tables that this function gets its data from to send emails:

1. emails
2. email_attachments

*emails* has the columns:

1. sequence
2. emailto
3. emailfrom
4. subject
5. message

and *email_attachmentss* has the columns:

1. sequence
2. email_seq (matches sequence from the emails table)
3. attachment

So i want to be able to select a row from the *emails* table and then select all the related rows in the *email_attachments* table and send all the attachments in one email

whats the best way to do this?

I usually do things like:

```
$sql="SELECT * from table1 where col = 'condition' ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $sql2="SELECT * from table2 where table1_col = '".$result["col"]."' ";
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
    $result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
}....
```

Comment: Use a JOIN, that's the normal way to get related data from two tables.

Comment: see my edit - thats how i usually link tables. i use JOIN sometimes but not all the time - not sure if my way above is easier?

Comment: Please be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and obsolete. You should consider converting your code to use the PDO library instead.

Answer (score 1):

Write a join query and then create an array and use foreach loop. Your join query should be something like this

```
"select e.email,e.sequence,e.emailto,e.emailfrom,e.subject,e.message,ea.email_seq, ea.attachment from email e join email_attachments ea on ea.email_seq = e.sequence;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following outer join:

```
SELECT e.sequence, e.emailto, e.emailfrom, e.subject, e.message, a.attachment
FROM emails e
LEFT JOIN email_attachments a ON a.email_seq = e.sequence
ORDER by e.sequence
```

Then loop over the rows from this. When the sequence is the same as the previous row, push the attachment onto an array of attachments (unless it's NULL, which will occur if there are no attachments associated with the email).